# How to write a program that asks the user to enter a string, converts it to ASCII Code then use Selection sort?

Tags: java

I know how to sort integers and how to convert a character into an ASCII code but I'm having some trouble how to put them together.

Basically I have this code that turns String to ASCII. But I'd like to use selection sort after it prints or before it prints. Do you know how?

```
public static void main (String [] args)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

    System.out.println("Enter Full Name: ");
    String str = input.readLine();

            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
                char c = str.charAt(i);
                int k = (int) c;
                    System.out.println(c + " = " + k);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `put them together` ? Do you want to sort one single `String` or multiple `String`s ?

Comment: Let's get some terminology straight.  Your program displays the numeric Unicode code-point for each character in an input string.  It so happens that Unicode code-points are equal to the ASCII encoding for 7-bit ASCII (values 0x20-0x7F, for backward compatibility).  If the user entered a non-ASCII character you would display its Unicode code point.  There is no ASCII anywhere in your code.

Comment: _"I'd like to use selection sort after it prints or before it prints"_ -- we have no idea what this means.  "Selection sort" of what dataset?  You will have to show some sample input and output.

Comment: oh sorry. That seems very confusing. Here's a sample output. Sorry about that.

Enter Full Name: 
Chris Isaac
C = 67
h = 104
r = 114
i = 105
s = 115
  = 32
I = 73
s = 115
a = 97
a = 97
c = 99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your issue. I have updated your source code and it is working as you expected.
Note few points :

1. Maintain an array to store ASCII values.
2. Print this array before selection Sort.
3. Call selectionSort method for sorting.
4. Print this array after selection sort.

Just copy paste this code should work.

```js
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class StackOverflow {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  
   BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

      System.out.println("Enter Full Name: ");

     
      String str = input.readLine();
      int[] array = new int[str.length()];;

              for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
                  char c = str.charAt(i);
                  int k = (int) c;
                  array[i] = k;
          }
  
   
        System.out.println("Before Selection Sort");  
        for(int i:array){  
            System.out.print(i+" ");  
        }  
        System.out.println();  
          
        selectionSort(array);//sorting array using selection sort  
         
        System.out.println("After Selection Sort");  
        for(int i:array){  
            System.out.print(i+" ");  
        }  
 }
 
 public static void selectionSort(int[] arr){  
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)  
        {  
            int index = i;  
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++){  
                if (arr[j] < arr[index]){  
                    index = j;//searching for lowest index  
                }  
            }  
            int smallerNumber = arr[index];   
            arr[index] = arr[i];  
            arr[i] = smallerNumber;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

ouput:

Enter Full Name:

ramesh

Before Selection Sort

114 97 109 101 115 104

After Selection Sort

97 101 104 109 114 115

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try storing the k values in an integer array of the same length as the string.
Then apply selection sort on it.

Like:

```
public static void main (String [] args)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));
    System.out.println("Enter Full Name: ");
    String str = input.readLine();
    int[] str_ascii = new int[str.length()];

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            char c = str.charAt(i);
            int k = (int) c;
            str_ascii[i] = k;
            System.out.println(c + " = " + k);
    }
          //now selection sort the array str_ascii 
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! :D